# KnockoutJS code suggestions in Brackets

Tags: knockout.js, autosuggest, adobe-brackets

I'm using Brackets for coding and I am just getting started with KnockoutJS. I downloaded the knockout.js file from their website and put it in my project folder alongside jQuery.

My problem is that when I want to write any Knockout code (ko.*), Brackets displays code suggestions but in their minified version/state. So instead of suggesting "applyBindings" for instance, it is suggesting "a, Aa, b, B...".

I have jQuery in minified version as well but the code hints are showing correctly for it. Any suggestions how to show correct hints for Knockout as well?

[Code hints for ko functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opY1C.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have a [source mapping file](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/) (jquery.min.map) for jQuery. It doesn't look like there is one available [on the CDN](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/knockout), so just use the debug version of Knockout for development. You can swap in the minified version for deployment.